# Using に対して to express "for," "for the purpose of," or "for verbing"

Tags: word-choice, nuances, definitions

> 日本語で一番難しいのは、**一つのことに対して**たくさんの言い方があることです。

Everything I can find on に対して says it means towards, against, regarding, in contrast to, etc.

In the above example sentence, it seems to mean something like "for the purpose of," standing in for the "for" in English.

How would you categorize this usage of に対して?

I guess the closest match is "regarding," but that feels like a stretch.

If one of the uses of に対して is "for verbing," how do I know when to use that instead of something like ために or anything else?

Comment: I'd say this 対して resembles "exchange rate 'for'" in English. Two for five dollars. Many wordings for one notion. You can put のために in its place and it surely means what you explain, and not same as the original sentence.